# Passagem de parametro de um fragmento para outro

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Não estou sabendo como trabalhar com dois fragmentos, procurei algumas coisa aqui mas não soube procurar direito.

De `Activity` para outra eu uso o `Bundle` e funciona, mas não estou sabendo usar com Fragment.

Eu estou trabalhando com Navigator Drawer que usam fragmentos. 
um dos fragmentos eu tenho um ListView e neste ListView eu preciso chamar outro fragmento com ListView também.

Ex. primeiro Fragmento/ListView (Anos) - 2016 - 2015 - 2014 - ....

Segue o código q estou usando no primeiro fragmento.

```
lv_Anos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // pegas os valores do Text no linha //
        TextView txAno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tx_Ano);
        // chamar outro fragment e passar paramentro para ele //
        // Variável ->> Param_Ano  


     }
});
```

O Segundo fragmento/ListView - Ediçoes

Preciso receber o Ano selecionado para gerar o Json do segundo fragmento.

Variável **Param_Ano**

```
new JSONTask().execute("http://www...../edicaoporano.php?Ano=" + Param_Ano);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar o bundle também, veja um exemplo:

Para enviar para outro Fragment

```
Seu_Fragment fragment = new Seu_Fragment(); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
bundle.putString("ano", Param_Ano); 
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.replace(viewID, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

E para receber no outro Fragment

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
if(mBundle != null){
   mBundle = getArguments();
   String ano = mBundle.getString("ano"); 
}
```

Agora no segundo Fragment, você tem a String **ano** populada com o valor que veio do primeiro fragment

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo, funcionou perfeitamente. 
Mas acabei tendo um outro problema agora, quando entra no segundo fragment não tem o botão de voltar para o primeiro fragment. vc saberia como fazer isso? valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Você pode voltar pelo botão fisico do aparelho, ou vc deseja colocar um botão?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer um, pode ser o fisico do aparelho mesmo se for mais fácil.